# jquery slider optimize ...maybe a CSS trick?

Tags: jquery, css

I customize **jQuery Slider** for a client project .
The result can be visualize here:

http://www.procuramed.com/ ....

check the bottom part ...you will notice a loop that slides .
My issue is that i have to adapt the background color of the slider piece corresponding to the value (red for 0 ....another low red for 0.5 ...green for 5 ) .
Currently i am using images combined into sprites but i am not very happy with it .

Any suggestion how to do it image less will help a lot !

Answer (score 0):

What about this here:
http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/
If that doesnt work for you, jQuery UI is also able to animate background colors: http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

EDIT: You could also use some of that code here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#colorpicker